# Group by / Distinct Sequelize query with functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, sequelize.js

I need to get the lowest value for each distinctly named item in a table. For example, for the following tables:

```
books
id| name
1 | math
2 | chem
3 | chem
4 | chem
5 | math

listings
id|bookID|price
1 |   1  | 4.35
2 |   2  | 2.54
3 |   3  | 1.57
4 |   4  | 4.91
5 |   5  | 7.22
```

The result of my query should return:

```
name | price
math | 4.35
chem | 1.57
```

The SQL query for this would be

```
SELECT b.name, MIN(l.price)
FROM Book b, Listing l 
WHERE b.id = l.bookId 
GROUP BY b.name;
```

I am having trouble trying to create a sequelize query that does the same... so far I have gotten this:

```
models.Listing.aggregate('book.name', 'models.Listing.min(price)', {
  distinct: true,
  include: [
    { model: models.Book, as: 'book' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: And what happens when you do that?

Comment: That causes a 404, but it was really just thrown together... I don't have a good understanding of how to construct queries in sequelized yet.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions are handled directly in the `attributes:` field using Sequelize Functions (`sequelize.fn()`).

```
models.Book.findAll({
  attributes: ['name'],
  include: [ {
     model: models.Listing,
     attributes: [[sequelize.fn('MIN', sequelize.col('price'), 'min_price']]
  } ]
})
.then(function (results) {
   return results.map(function (book) {
     return {
       name: book.name,
       price: book.listing.get('min_price')
     };
   });
});
```

The use of `sequelize.col` instead of a field name string makes sure that Sequelize knows you're referring to a column, not a passed in value.

Also, the alias `min_price` must be added if you want to use it from the model. (i.e. `listing_inst.get('min_price')`).

Here's a link to the docs: http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/querying/#attributes

Unfortunately, you can't really just return an object that has fields from both tables directly (unnested) without a raw query. But, you can just squish them together in the `then()`